# Linear curve_fit always yields a slope and y-intercept of 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I am trying to do a linear fit of some data, but I cannot get curve_fit in Python to give me anything but a slope and y-intercept of 1. Here is an example of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b

# This is merely a sample of some of my actual data
x = [290., 300., 310.]
y = [1.87e+21, 2.07e+21, 2.29e+21]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

print popt
```

I have also tried giving curve_fit a "guess," but when I do that it gives me an overflow error, which I'm guessing is because the numbers are too large.

Comment: When I divide your y-values by 1e21, I get fit values that are not 1. Maybe you could fit to smaller y-values and then scale the result

Comment: The default initial parameters for curve_fit() are all 1.0, so when no fit can be done only the initial parameter estimates are available - and all 1.0 as in this case.

Comment: ams, I am still getting a slope of 1 even when I divide out the 1e21. Can I see your code?

Comment: @ams, I am still getting a slope of 1 even when I divide out the 1e21. Can I see your code?

Comment: Do you have to use `curve_fit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this without using `curve_fit` is to use numpy's [polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# This is merely a sample of some of my actual data
x = [290., 300., 310.]
y = [1.87e+21, 2.07e+21, 2.29e+21]

xp = np.linspace(290, 310, 100)

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
print (z)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, '.')
ax.plot(xp, p(xp), '-')

plt.show()
```

This prints the coefficients as `[2.10000000e+19  -4.22333333e+21]` and produces the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got something in the ballpark as Excel's linear fit by using scipy basinhopping instead of curve_fit with a large number of iterations. It takes a bit to run the iterations and it also requires an error function, but it was done without scaling the original data. [Basinhopping docs.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping

def func( x0, x_data, y_data ):

    error = 0
    for x_val, y_val in zip(x_data, y_data): 
        error += (y_val - (x0[0]*x_val + x0[1]))**2

    return error

x_data = [290., 300., 310.]
y_data = [1.87e+21, 2.07e+21, 2.29e+21]
a = 1
b = 1
x0 = [a, b]

minimizer_kwargs = { 'method': 'TNC', 'args': (x_data, y_data) }

res = basinhopping(func, x0, niter=1000000, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)

print res
```

This gives x: array([  7.72723434e+18,  -2.38554994e+20]) but if you try again, you'll see this has the problem of non-unique outcomes, although it will give similar ballpark values.

Here's a comparison of the fit with the Excel solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed correct results are returned using:

```
x = [290., 300., 310.]
y = [300., 301., 302.]
```

My guess is magnitudes `≅ 10²¹` are too large for the function to work well.

What you can try doing is taking the logarithm of both sides:

```
def func(x, a, b):
    # might need to check if ≤ 0.0
    return math.log(a*x + b)

# ... code omitted

y = [48.9802253837, 49.0818355602, 49.1828387704]
```

Then undo the transformation afterwards.

Also for simple linear approximation, there is an easy deterministic method.